# rails get a list of records by checking if association is approved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

I've got a organization model and an organization_profile model. The organization_profile model has an approved column. I would like to be able to find all approved users by calling something like: Organization.approved. I found that the best way to handle this is probably through scope. However I can't seem to get it to work. This is what i am trying

```
scope :approved, -> {joins(:organization_profile).where('organization_profile.approved = ?', true) }
```

But then Organization.approved gives me all kinds of errors:

```
Organization Load (8.0ms)  SELECT "organizations".* FROM "organizations" INNER JOIN "organization_profiles" ON "organization_profiles"."user_id" = "organizations"."id" WHERE (organization_profile.approved = 't')
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "organization_profile"
LINE 1: ...profiles"."user_id" = "organizations"."id" WHERE (organizati...
                                                         ^
: SELECT "organizations".* FROM "organizations" INNER JOIN "organization_profiles" ON "organization_profiles"."user_id" = "organizations"."id" WHERE (organization_profile.approved = 't')
```

Can anyone tell me the correct code?

Comment: Something like this should work: `User.approved`

Comment: I updated my question, If i use that I get errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is using `organization_profile` (singular) but your table name is `organization_profiles` (plural).

A slightly better way to do this (which also avoids using strings), is to turn the where clause into an Arel predicate (might not be the right word):

```
scope :approved, -> { joins(:organization_profile).where(OrganizationProfile.arel_table['approved'].eq(true)) }
```

Answer (score 1):

The condition is SQL code that should reflect correctly the name of your tables which are always plural :

```
where('organization_profiles.approved = ?', true)
```